# Can SharedPreferences be not saving?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have one application that uses SharedPreferences to record the checkin or checkout state of the user.
If the checkin is pressed, it's button is grayed out the checkout becomes available, the opposite work as well.

However some users tells me that "sometimes" they will make another checkin on the next day and the checkout is still available.

Im supecting that they are forgetting to tap it, but i want to know if is there by any chance that this SharedPreferencces get cleared by itself?

this is the part of my code that i save the checkin state:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("statuscheckin", 1);    //1 for checkin, 0 for checkout            
            editor.commit();
```

this is the part where i check it

```
if (getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("statuscheckin", 0) == 1) {...}
```

Comment: Its possible that you are retrieving value before Commit . Debug your code cause we do not know where you put this piece of code . `SharedPreferences` will not get cleared it self.

Comment: @ADM ive checked if there might be another possibility but the program is straight forward, the first line of code is checking if it is a checkin or checkout so i retrieve data. Then is user press a button it runs code of commit. Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you clear the storage/cache, SharedPreferences won't get cleared by itself.

- Make sure you are not clearing it by yourself for any condition happening.
- If you are getting the default value only, it's possible that you are using it before the value gets committed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

Session Manager code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context context;

public static final String KEY_CHECKIN= "checkin";

public void setCheckin(boolean login){
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(KEY_CHECKIN,checkin);
    editor.apply();
}

public boolean getCheckin(){
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_CHECKIN,false);
}
```

In your Java code:

```
SessionManager sessionmanager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
sessionmanager = new SessionManager(this);
```

//Condition for checkin

```
if(user checkedIn){
sessionmanager.setCheckin(true);}
```

//Retrieving the value when user again opens the app:

```
if(sessionmanager.getCheckin()){}////proceed with your logic.
```

Comment: Try not to post some random Utility class cause this does not indicate the problem with OP's code . I am not denying the fact that it can solve the problem but still Problem need to address first then solution this is what i call learning .

Comment: Okay Cool...@ADM